# How the PS1 of the title doesn't overwrite the PS1 of the prompt

Tags: bash, terminal, ps1

I noticed that in `~/.bashrc` there are two sets of `PS1`:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$'
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

The first one checks for `$color_prompt`, if it true or not and decides for the **text of the prompt**.
The second one checks for `$TERM` and decides for the **title**.

But both of them changes the **same** environment variable, so when the terminal starts and "see" that `PS1` is set for the **text of the prompt**, how it can also set the title?  Is `~/.bashrc` being loaded twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first condition sets `$PS1` according to whether `$color_prompt` is enabled or not. The second assigned extends this by setting `$PS1` to an expression **the contains the previous value of `$PS1`**

```
PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\a\]$PS1"
# Here ---------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Oh I see, I missed it. Thanks you